# Group the count values

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I want to get the count of property and building and building is linked with property. Below is the query I tried:

```
select
    PT.PropertyTypeName,
    Count(PropertyID) as ProperyCount,
    Isnull((Select count(B.BuildingID)
            from Building B
            join Property P1
                on B.PropertyID=P1.PropertyID
            where B.PropertyID =P.PropertyID), 0) as BuildingsCount
from Property P
join PropertyType PT
    on PT.PropertyTypeID = P.PropertyTypeID
left join AssetToFund AF
    on AF.AssetID = P.AssetID
left join Fund F
    on F.FundID = AF.FundID
left join Asset A
    on A.AssetID = P.AssetID
left join Client C
    on C.ClientID = F.ClientID
where C.ClientId=10000001
group by PT.PropertyTypeName,P.PropertyID
```

I expect values group of type

and I want to group the count with out duplicate of property-type name

Comment: Please add sample data and your current and expected output. We can't fix this query without knowing what your data is.

Answer (score 0):

sry for bad English.

Try to use the SUM() function on this subquery

> Returns the sum of all the values, or only the DISTINCT values, in the expression. SUM can be used with numeric columns only. Null values are ignored.
>   [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SUM(Select count(B.BuildingID)
from Building B
join Property P1
on B.PropertyID=P1.PropertyID
where B.PropertyID = P.PropertyID)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `GROUP BY` then it groups data by columns which you've written in `GROUP BY` statement. You've written :

```
GROUP BY PT.PropertyTypeName,P.PropertyID`
```

it means that SQL Engine will get all unique combinations of `PropertyTypeName, PropertyID`. However, you want just unique `PropertyTypeName`. So write just this field into `GROUP BY` statement:

```
GROUP BY PT.PropertyTypeName
```

So complete query will look like this:

```
select
    PT.PropertyTypeName,
    Count(PropertyID) as ProperyCount,
    Isnull((Select count(B.BuildingID)
            from Building B
            join Property P1
                on B.PropertyID=P1.PropertyID
            where B.PropertyID =P.PropertyID), 0) as BuildingsCount
from Property P
join PropertyType PT
    on PT.PropertyTypeID = P.PropertyTypeID
left join AssetToFund AF
    on AF.AssetID = P.AssetID
left join Fund F
    on F.FundID = AF.FundID
left join Asset A
    on A.AssetID = P.AssetID
left join Client C
    on C.ClientID = F.ClientID
where C.ClientId=10000001
group by PT.PropertyTypeName
```